# SQL server ensure computed column does not become minus

Tags: sql-server

If I have the following Query to compute Employees Sick leave remaining

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Employee]
ADD [SickLeaveEntitlementRemaining]  AS (case 

                when getdate()>=datefromparts(datepart(year,[StartDate]),datepart(month,[StartDate]),datepart(day,[StartDate])) AND getdate()<=dateadd(month,(6),datefromparts(datepart(year,[StartDate]),datepart(month,[StartDate]),datepart(day,[StartDate]))) then (0)-[SickLeaveTaken] 
                when getdate()>=dateadd(month,(6),datefromparts(datepart(year,[StartDate]),datepart(month,[StartDate]),datepart(day,[StartDate]))) AND getdate()<=dateadd(year,(1),datefromparts(datepart(year,[StartDate]),datepart(month,[StartDate]),datepart(day,[StartDate]))) then (8)-[SickLeaveTaken] 
                when getdate()>=dateadd(year,(1),datefromparts(datepart(year,[StartDate]),datepart(month,[StartDate]),datepart(day,[StartDate]))) AND getdate()<=dateadd(year,(3),datefromparts(datepart(year,[StartDate]),datepart(month,[StartDate]),datepart(day,[StartDate]))) then (24)-[SickLeaveTaken] 
                when getdate()>=dateadd(year,(3),datefromparts(datepart(year,[StartDate]),datepart(month,[StartDate]),datepart(day,[StartDate]))) AND getdate()<=dateadd(year,(1000),datefromparts(datepart(year,[StartDate]),datepart(month,[StartDate]),datepart(day,[StartDate]))) then (40)-[SickLeaveTaken]  end)
```

How would I ensure that this value never becomes minus, as sometimes the `sickLeaveTaken` would be greater than the `SickLeaveEntitlementRemaining`

Comment: You won't be able to add a constraint to that column, as it isn't deterministic. What value are you therefore expecting if the value would be less than 0?

Comment: If someone takes more sick leave than they are allotted, you don't want to show that?

Comment: @Larnu If the computed column was a negative, I'd like a value of 0 to be set

Comment: Do you want to prevent updates to that table with a SickLeave greater than your rule??

Comment: What is with all those datefromparts? Are you just turning that into a date? Why not simply convert(date, StartDate)?

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean No, not really as I've all records set in another table which tracks the amount of sick leave taken

Comment: @SeanLange I'm using them for business rules which determine how much sick leave each employee gets. The output of this column is a decimal

Comment: Personally, I think the approach is wrong here. You should really have a ledger type of table that shows time accrued/granted/earned along with time taken; it should then be a calculation against that table. Also, having hard coded values isn't going to scale. If you expand to a different state/country or acquire a different company, the values can easily change for some employees and not others.

Comment: What Sean said. Sick leave (remaining or granted) is something that changes over time. A person is allocated leave on a regular basis (yearly, payperiod, etc) and that amount is consumed over time. There is no single number here. And I can tell you that HR will want to know these values for any given date during a person's career.

Comment: @SMor Yes I have a record of where these numbers come from. All request are tracked on another table

Comment: You might want to read a great blog post called [Properly getting into jail:
it’s not a crime to be in an invalid state](https://ayende.com/blog/182050-A/properly-getting-into-jail-its-not-a-crime-to-be-in-an-invalid-state) which further considers situations where you may have to *accept* data that's invalid per business rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want values less than 0 to be 0, then i would do this:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Employee]
ADD [SickLeaveEntitlementRemaining] AS (CASE
                                             WHEN GETDATE() >= CONVERT(date, Startdate)
                                              AND GETDATE() <= DATEADD(MONTH, (6), CONVERT(date, Startdate)) THEN IIF((0) - [SickLeaveTaken] < 0, 0, (0) - [SickLeaveTaken])
                                             WHEN GETDATE() >= DATEADD(MONTH, (6), CONVERT(date, Startdate))
                                              AND GETDATE() <= DATEADD(YEAR, (1), CONVERT(date, Startdate)) THEN IIF((8) - [SickLeaveTaken] < 0, 0, (8) - [SickLeaveTaken])
                                             WHEN GETDATE() >= DATEADD(YEAR, (1), CONVERT(date, Startdate))
                                              AND GETDATE() <= DATEADD(YEAR, (3), CONVERT(date, Startdate)) THEN IIF((24) - [SickLeaveTaken] < 0, 0, (24) - [SickLeaveTaken])
                                             WHEN GETDATE() >= DATEADD(YEAR, (3), CONVERT(date, Startdate))
                                              AND GETDATE() <= DATEADD(YEAR, (1000), CONVERT(date, Startdate)) THEN IIF((40) - [SickLeaveTaken] < 0, 0, (40) - [SickLeaveTaken])
                                        END);
```

Note, as Sean mentioned, that I also shortened down that massive `DATEFROMPARTS` expression down to a `CONVERT`; making this far more readable.

Personally, however, I feel this isn't a good idea. If someone *has* used more sick leave than they should, you should be aware. This is what the OP has asked for, however, there are *"better"* solutions. Especially if you want to **stop** someone using more leave than they are entitled to.

Comment: Thank you, I was unaware of using the convert method as I am quite new to SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Your rule can be simplified this way

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Employee]
    ADD [SickLeaveEntitlementRemaining]  AS ( 
        CASE 
            WHEN DATEDIFF(Year, StartDate, GETDATE()) >= 3 THEN IIF((40) - [SickLeaveTaken] < 0, 0, (40) - [SickLeaveTaken])
            WHEN DATEDIFF(Year, StartDate, GETDATE()) >= 1 THEN IIF((24) - [SickLeaveTaken] < 0, 0, (24) - [SickLeaveTaken])
            WHEN DATEDIFF(Month, StartDate, GETDATE()) >= 6 THEN IIF((8) - [SickLeaveTaken] < 0, 0, (8) - [SickLeaveTaken])
            ELSE 0 
        END
    )
```